# "The type or namespace name 'Route' could not be found" using "attribute routing"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

Just trying to splice some code from one working project to another.  The "from" project uses "attribute routing" where you embed `[Route(…)]` directives in the Web API controller modules to indicate what HTTP message should route to what service routine.

Works fine in the "from" project, but in the "to" project I get the build error "The type or namespace name 'Route' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I've tried copying essentially all of the `using` statements from the "from" project to the "to" project, but that has no apparent effect.  None of the MS documentation suggests that a NuGet package is required (or even a `using` statement).  Both projects are supposedly ASP.NET MVC 4.

(And, yes, I updated WebApiConfig.cs with the `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` statement.)

Any ideas??

Comment: I think I remember it being a web api 2 feature, I thought that was "bundled" with MVC4 projects...Scratch that I think I am getting confused. No.....Im half there, try Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost

Comment: There are so many #%$@ versions floating around in a VS project I don't know what to check.  Both projects import the MVC 4 NuGet package.  Beyond that I don't know.

Comment: OK, I see that "from" imports the Web API 2 package while the "to" imports Web API-nothing.  I'll see if upgrading fixes it or causes the end of the universe as we know it.

Comment: ha ha.  DLL hell is alive and well (well of a slightly different variety)....Its heart warming, was just enjoying similar pain at work today, deep joy :)

Comment: @brumScouse - Installed "Web API 2.1 Web Host" and the 4 errors related to Route went away.  Of course, two new ones appeared.  Thanks! (I think)

Comment: Well hopefully you can get on to your next set of problems!  I think just talking about it helped :)

Comment: @brumScouse - Yeah, consider that I bought you a virtual beer.

Comment: @brumScouse thanks man, I did an 'Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost -reinstall' and it worked. Funny this happens after getting the latest version on different PCs from TFS. I guess this happens because of nuget packages not working properly with the versioning system.

Comment: Please check this blog it may help you http://sreerejith.blogspot.in/2015/07/url-rewriting-in-mvc-4-attribute-routing.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Attribute Routing is native in ASP.NET MVC 5, or later, and ASP.NET Web API 2.

For previous versions you can use one of the packages from the [AttributeRouting project](http://mccalltd.github.io/AttributeRouting/) that allows to use attribute routing in previous version of ASP.NET MVC, and Web API. The availabe nuget packages are:

- `Install-Package AttributeRouting` (for MVC)
- `Install-Package AttributeRouting.WebApi` (for Web API)
- `Install-Package AttributeRouting.WebApi.Hosted` (for self-hosted Web API)

Please, be aware that the namespaces of attribute routing are different for each version, so you must review the project soruces code, or browse the .dll included by the installed package, to find out the right namespace, and change your `using` accordingly. For example:

```
using AttributeRouting.Web.Http;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, installing the AttributeRouting package does not make the messages go away.  (I have a "using System.Web.Http.Routing;" in the module.)

Comment: That's logical. The namespace is different. You must get sure which version of Web API are using. The attributes to use depend on versions (of MVC and Web API ) and if it's Web API, self hosted Web API or MVC.

Comment: Thel link is dead, so I provide link to GH: https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting

Answer (score 32):

This comment from Vedran Mandić solved the problem for me.  I'm re-posting it here because I think it should be the answer (or at least a answer).

> I did an 'Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost -reinstall'
>   and it worked. Funny this happens after getting the latest version on
>   different PCs from TFS. I guess this happens because of nuget packages
>   not working properly with the versioning system

Comment: this rocks. Same problem here with TFS and nuget

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip, but I personally hate this kind of fix.  It usually involves lots of head banging, wasted time and frustration.

Comment: Oddly - updated VS2019 from 16.7.5 to 16.8.2 (latest) and had to do this. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 5):

In my case, in web api project there were two using references:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

As soon as I removed `System.Web.Mvc`, the error was gone.

Comment: Still getting error. `[RoutePrefix("xxx")]` taking referance but still `[Route("xxx")]` unavalible.

Comment: Me too.  UNTIL I followed the advice from ClearCloud8 (above)

Answer (score 0):

When projects are shared between multiple solutions, the reference of libraries downloaded with *Nuget* have to be configured in *.csproj* manually at solution related path.

For example, log4net should be configured as:

```
<Reference Include="log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>$(SolutionDir)\packages\log4net.2.0.5\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll</HintPath>
   <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```