# Routing - WebAPI and MVC in one project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have 2 controllers. Both dealing with Bar (a child of Foo).

One of them is for MVC which returns views.

```
[Route("Foo/Bar")]
public class FooBarController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public IActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

One of them is for the API, which exists under a *folder* of "api".

```
[Route("api/Foo/Bar")]
[ApiController]
public class FooBarAPIController : ControllerBase
{
    //
}
```

Without adding the following line to the FooBarController class, I can access the API controller (for example: /api/foo/bar/{id}), and the MVC controller (for example: /FooBar/SomeAction)

> [Route("Foo/Bar")]

But when I do, routing is messed up and I get the following error trying to access /Foo/Bar/SomeAction

> AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
>
> Controllers.MVC.FooBarController.Index
>
> Controllers.MVC.FooBarController.SomeAction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it (to be appear to be) working using the following.

```
[Route("Foo/Bar")]
[Route("Foo/Bar/[action]")]
public class FooBarController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SomeAction");
    }

    public IActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don't have the attribute applied, FooBarController uses conventional routing, which you probably have already by default. It normally has Index as the default action, and allow you to also specify the action name, thus everything works.

When you apply the attribute, all actions in this controller now use attribute routing. These two routing types aren't combined, you can only use one or the other. Note that

> "With attribute routing the controller name and action names play no
>   role in which action is selected."

([docs source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2)). So these two actions become the same, their names ignored, and it is impossible to figure out which one to use. So you need to help it:

```
[Route("Foo/Bar")]
public class FooBarController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("")]      // To make it default for "Foo/Bar"
    [Route("Index")] // Combines to define the route template "Foo/Bar/Index"
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // ...
    }

    [Route("SomeAction")] // Combines to define the route template "Foo/Bar/SomeAction"
    public IActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Yes, it is more verbose. From the same source:

> Attribute routing requires more input to specify a route; the
>   conventional default route handles routes more succinctly. However,
>   attribute routing allows (and requires) precise control of which route
>   templates apply to each action.

Comment: Ah, thanks for this. I figured this was the case, but I don't want to use Attribute Routing with the MVC controller (just the API controller). Is there an attribute that will change the controller route (without changing it to Attribute Routing) that I can apply to the controller (and not startup.cs)?

Comment: @Beakie What do you mean by `I don't want to use Attribute Routing with the MVC`? As your description, it works without `[Route("Foo/Bar")]`.

Answer (score 1):

For your API controller, I recommend changing `Route` to `RoutePrefix["api"]`, this way all of your api methods would then contain just the route (hopefully a different name than what you have for your Home Controller.

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class MyApiController : ApiController 
{
    [HttpGet, Route("foo/bar")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSomething()
    {
        //do something when routing to /api/foo/bar
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("foobar/foobar")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSomething()
    {
        //do something when routing to /api/foobar/foobar
    }
}
```

Same advice goes to your HomeController (if you really want to add a route to it, and every method within that class will be routed according to their method name eg. `Index`)

```
[RoutePrefix("foo/bar")]
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(); //or something
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View(); //or something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What namespace is RoutePrefix in?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419324/the-type-or-namespace-name-route-could-not-be-found-using-attribute-routing

Answer (score 1):

If you want to route `FooBarController.SomeAction` with `/Foo/Bar/SomeAction`, you could try something like

```
    [Route("Foo/Bar/[action]")]
    public class FooBarController : ControllerBase
    {
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                    // ...
            }

            public IActionResult SomeAction()
            {
                    // ...
            }
    }
```